# Why is a structure with holes and gaps stronger than a completely solid counterpart?

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I often see abstract material designs like this http://news.mit.edu/2017/3-d-graphene-strongest-lightest-materials-0106

Why are such abstract shapes stronger than just a completely solid cube/cylinder counterpart?

Comment: Are you comparing two different shapes where the shapes have  the same mass?

Answer (score 1):

They are not. Holes and hollow spaces get built into structures to save weight, and to save on the cost of the exotic high-strength material from which it is fashioned.

Comment: But maybe the extra amount of each material puts unnecessary pressure on underlying atoms in the direction of compression and is more likely to cause structural failure. If there really is no difference, why is the construction of a building limited by the force of gravity?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Gravity limits how tall you can build something because eventually the weight of a material compresses itself beyond the material's fracture point. In a similar way, compression applied to a smaller but weaker object can cause the same kind of failure where a portion of a material slips over itself and causes a fracture. If there's just empty space though, a material has more room to deform before transferring stress to an underlying layer transverse to the motion of compression.